# Автоматическая обрезка значений из файла свойств Spring

Tags: java, spring

Есть ли какие-либо возможности для автоматической обрезки значений из файлов свойств *Spring*?

Например, у меня есть свойство в файле *application.properties*:

```
server.numbers = sss01, sss04
```

и, соответственно, получаю я этот массив значений в коде следующим образом:

```
@Value("${server.numbers:}")
private String[] numbers;
```

И при этом после получения я должна обрезать пробелы, выполнив для каждого элемента массива операцию `trim()`. А есть ли возможность сделать это автоматически, средствами *Spring*, например, посредством аннотации?

Comment: Одно из решений написать свой кастомный `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` как указано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031905/automatically-trim-trailing-white-space-for-properties-in-props-file-loaded-into)

Comment: @Nikolay, да, хороший вопрос) просто в файле свойств на самом деле была другие значение (уже отредактировала сообщение, чтобы оно более соответствовало реальности), а при написании сообщения я удалила символы перед номерами)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я попробовал воспроизвести ваш пример и у меня все работает "из коробки" (spring 1.5.9):

```
@Component
public class NumbersComponent {
    @Value("${server.numbers:}")
    private String[] numbers;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        Arrays.stream(numbers).map(n -> "|" + n + "|").forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Результат:

> |sss01|
>   |sss04|